# SubView Constraints

Tags: ios, swift

Can't seem to figure it out, my UIEdgeInsets for left/right aren't effected when I build the app in the simulator. Besides that problem I want my UICollectionView cells in 3 items a row but all I get is the cells underneat each other and they are very LONG. Where do I go wrong?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 100)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Your code,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 100)  >>>> You are applying parent view width(full width) to item width
}
```

Add below code to `sizeForItemAt` method to get your desired output

```
//define constant value as per your requirement and declare this variables globally
let inset: CGFloat = 10 //define as per your requirement
let minimumInteritemSpacing: CGFloat = 10 //define as per your requirement
let cellsPerRow = 3

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
   let marginsAndInsets = inset * 2 + collectionView.safeAreaInsets.left + collectionView.safeAreaInsets.right + minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(cellsPerRow - 1)
        
   let itemWidth = ((collectionView.bounds.size.width - marginsAndInsets) / CGFloat(cellsPerRow)).rounded(.down)
   
   return .init(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make it like this to display three cells by row
func

```
 let spaceBetweenCells: CGFloat = 10
 collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.width - 2* spaceBetweenCells)/3, height: 100)
    }
```

Comment: Hi Esraa, thanks for your reply but I'm getting the following errors:
- '*' is not a postfix unary operator
- Expected ',' separator
Insert ','
- Use of unresolved identifier 'spaceBetweenCells'

Comment: put this in the top of the method our outside it:
let spaceBetweenCells: CGFloat = 10

"spaceBetweenCells" is a number that should be your Space between the cells.